# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large (service config vs client config)

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, web-config, app-config, endpoint

There are a number of post already out there but I cannot get this to work. The posts suggest to define the tags endpoints and binding both client side and server side. All I have is the applications web.config file. How do I make the distinction between client side and server side. In my web.config, i defined a services tag, but it seems as if it is not used as the face binding configurations defined in there is never called out when debugging. My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="****" type="****, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*********" >
       <section name="********" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*********" requirePermission="false" />
     </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
           <binding name="binding1_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
               <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
               </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="binding2_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                     <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                     <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http:aaa.com/bbb.xamlx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding1_IService" contract="App.IAppService"  />
        <endpoint address="http:aaa.com/bbb.xamlx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding2_IService" contract="App2.IApp2Service"  />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

   <!--Not sure this is where to put this and if it is correct -->
   <services>
     <service  name="namespace.classname">
        <endpoint  address="http:aaa.com/bbb.xamlx" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="App.IAppService" bindingConfiguration="binding1.IService" />
        <endpoint address="http:aaa.com/bbb.xamlx" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="App.IAppService2" bindingConfiguration="binding2.IService" />
      </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
     <customErrors mode="Off" />
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
     <authentication mode="Windows" />
     <authorization>
         <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
 </system.webServer>
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="name" connectionString="string" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I keep getting the error above when uploading non-text files. Any help please...

Comment: I'm getting the same error from my xamlx. Where you able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with xamlx (Windows Workflow Foundation Web Services), and I tried a bunch of WCF solutions with no success, but I found the following solution on the asp.net forum; which worked perfectly even on IIS Express.

Reference: [Problem with XAMLX service in .Net 4.0](http://forums.asp.net/p/1663742/5746695.aspx?p=True&t=635423198289891653&pagenum=1)